# How to set a 'dataset open option' in ogr on a file geodatabase?

Tags: gdal, ogr

In the documentation for the GDAL/OGR OpenFileGDB driver, there is a Dataset open option called LIST_ALL_TABLES. Using python, how exactly do I set that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example from the GDAL Python tests
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_openfilegdb.py#L2115

```
 # Test LIST_ALL_TABLES=YES open option
    ds_all_table = gdal.OpenEx(
        "data/filegdb/testopenfilegdb.gdb.zip",
        gdal.OF_VECTOR,
        open_options=["LIST_ALL_TABLES=YES"],
    )
```

Comment: Yes! that does it! Thank you. Although it may be worth noting that when using `gdal.OpenEx`, you can't use `for layer in ds:` like you can when you use ogr.Open(). But right below that snippet at the github page is the iteration `layer_names = [ds_all_table.GetLayer(i).GetName() for i in range(ds_all_table.GetLayerCount())]`

Answer (score 2):

For information, this is also possible using fiona, a library that offers alternative, more "pythonic", bindings to GDAL:

```
tables = fiona.listlayers(
    "data/filegdb/testopenfilegdb.gdb.zip", list_all_tables="YES"
)
```

Comment: I wish I could use Fiona! For now I am constrained to the packages that are in the default ArcGIS Pro environment which does not include Fiona and has only a part of the full GDAL library. I want to make my tool usable to other Pro users without the hurdle of cloning the default env and adding packages.